# angular append array of objects to textarea starting from new line

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to add value to textarea from scope's array starting with new line and i found a good example here but seems like it works only with array of primitives.

```
$scope.names = ['morpheus', 'neo', 'trinity'];
```

But what if i need to use array of js objects like this:

```
$scope.namesObj = [
            {name: 'morpheus'},
            {name: 'neo'},
            {name: 'trinity'}
         ]
```

As you can see in [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jLwXlOvWcMQmu2IMu0FL?p=preview) it shows only

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

I can't find a way how to get property `name`.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question...but if you just want an easy way to deal with non-primitive objects in your array, you may use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
$scope.namesObj = [
    {name: 'morpheus'},
    {name: 'neo'},
    {name: 'trinity'}
]
.map(function(item){
    return item.name;
});
```

Here's your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xShKGn2DwMZPgpK319V5?p=preview

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what i wanted! Thank you a lot.